# Linear regression with large dataset in r - why does my regression work only work if I scale the data?

Tags: r, linear-regression, large-data, lm

I am currently trying to calculate several linear regressions with a large dataset in R (around 2 million observations) which have around 10 variables. Most of the variables are values between 0 and 100. If I try to run my regression with the function `lm()`, it produces the following error:

```
Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)
```

After scaling my variables with this function:

```
rescale(df$var1, to = c(0, 1))
```

R is suddenly able to calculate my regressions. Do you have any idea why R is only able to calculate my coefficients when I convert my variables with `rescale`?
Furthermore, do you know any more efficient linear models I could use? I have also tried `biglm()` but it caused the same error for me with the unscaled numbers.

Comment: That's a really tough question to answer without any details. It looks like you're fairly new to SO; welcome to the community! If you want great answers quickly, it's best to make your question reproducible. This includes sample data like the output from `dput(head(dataObject)))` and any libraries you are using. Check it out: [making R reproducible questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269).

Comment: Check if `df$var1`  might be stored under the wrong type (e.g as Character or factor). `typeof(df$var1)`, you might need to convert it to a numeric type first.

Comment: @Kat thanks for the link, I definitely need to improve on that!

Comment: @Sandwichnick it worked now after converting it with as.numeric() - thank you so much!!!